# Pdf reader + Latex with hyperlinks to references

Tags: pdf, latex

Is it possible to have a [pdf reader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software)/reader plugin for Ubuntu that can automatically navigate [Latex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latex) references as hyperlinks?

Usually, the hyperlinking depends on whether or not a pdf document has been created with the hyperlinking package or not; is it possible to have a pdf reader that does this for documents which were not compiled with hyperlinks?

*Perhaps an example is in order. I read quite a lot of Physics publications written and compiled via Latex format. In these publications, they always cite other publications with e.g. 'Physicist et al. 2011' and the details of this publication can be found at the end of the pdf document. Latex has the option of compiling with hyperlinks; this means one would be able to click on the 'Physicist et al. 2011' and jump right to the details of the publication. Not all journals compile with hyperlinks, however, and so having a reader that does this automatically would be immensely helpful.*

Comment: Once the LaTeX is compiled into a PDF, any additional information about the reference is lost, such as a URL field in the BibTeX, so I don't think this is possible. Could you link to an example PDF?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment; here's one article using hyperlinks for citing: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00017.pdf

So for example when [1] is pressed, it jumps to the corresponding source for citation. In most publications this won't happen.